# how to sort aggregate - Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
db.getCollection('shows').aggregate([
                     { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5d622cecbbe890f60ccd1ca4") } },

                     {  $lookup: { from: "episode", // collection name in db
                                   localField: "_id",
                                   foreignField: "show_id",
                                   as: "episode"
                                   }
                     },
                     { $sort: { 'episode._id': 1 } }
                   ])
```

So the below works fine however it seems that the sort is not sorting the collection episode in the correct order. It is still putting it oldest to newest when I want to have it newest to oldest.

I am wondering how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  below aggregation

```
db.getCollection("shows").aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("5d622cecbbe890f60ccd1ca4") } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "episode",
    "let": { "episodeId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$show_id", "$$episodeId"] }}},
      { "$sort": { "_id": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "episode"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be ```{ "$sort": { "_id": -1 }}``` as the output should be **newest to oldest.**

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma Depends on OP's choice. I just wanted to let him know about the new syntax of `$lookup`.